# Calculating moving majority in R

Tags: r

I´m trying to calculate moving majority values over an raster in R. The focal function in the raster package just provides mean, min and max. I have a raster with 3 values (1, 2 and 3) and I would like to have the value most abundant in a 3x3 window set in the center.

How can I do that most efficient in R? Thank you!

```
library(raster)

# create data
r <- raster(nrows = 120, ncol = 120, xmn=0)
r[] <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
f <- function(x){
 tab <- table(x)
 # I am using the first value here, maybe you want to use the mean, 
 # if 2 or more values occur equally often.
 names(tab)[which.max(tab)][1]
}

r <- raster(nrows = 120, ncol = 120, xmn=0)
r[] <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)

r <- focal(r, w=3, f)
```

Comment: Good approach.  I used `table` in a homebrew function to calculate the ensemble mode value(s).  Naturally I can't find that code right now    :-(

Comment: Please note that this approach still works in `terra` but, the `modal` call to `focal` (via @maycca) does not work outside of `raster`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I am little bit late, but it could be useful for futurs readers:

Now in R you can find focal function for majority (mode), so:

```
library(raster)

# create data
r <- raster(nrows = 120, ncol = 120, xmn=0)
r[] <- sample(3, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)

a<-focal(r, w=matrix(1,3,3), fun=modal)    # 3x3 moving window
plot(a)
```

*(NOTE: make attention whenusing NA values - it worth better to convert them to integer number)*

result:

[image: result from focal analysis]